# Select as JSON object {key: {}}

Tags: json, postgresql, plpgsql

My table:

```
ID | something1 | something2 | ...
1  | meow       | 5          |
2  | 4          | KITTIES    |
```

Is there any way to select data as JSON in format `{"1":{"something1":"meow","something2":5},"2":{...}}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind repeating the ID field in the JSON representation of a row, you can do:

```
SELECT 
  format('{%s}',
    string_agg(
      format(
        '%s:%s',
        to_json(ID::text),
        row_to_json(my_table)
      ), ','
    ), ''
  )::json as json_object
FROM my_table;
```

This gives you a JSON object containing a sub-object for each row in the table, keyed by the value in the ID field.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e7364/17)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006291/postgresql-return-result-set-as-json-array) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this library](https://github.com/begriffs/postgrest) to get an API of the database. Then, consume it! This is the fastest and clearest thing I can imagine.