# PLSQL Procedure to return result set without a refcursor

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

So Im going trough an oracle database course and I have a homework where I have to create a procedure and "return" (I guess return) the resultset without using a refcursor, but all the examples I find make use of it.

So lets say I have this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_all_inventory() AS
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM Inventory;
END;
/
```

How do I make the procedure return the resultset without using refcursor?
is this even possible?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** If someone know a way of returning the result set in json that will be just awesome!

Comment: go through this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/appdev.112/e18751/procedures_plsql.htm#TDPNG60040. You will get a detail idea

Comment: It is possible to return as json. please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006291/postgresql-return-result-set-as-json-array

Answer (score 1):

Aside from using JSON, you can also use collections as a return value. You have to create a package first for your procedure. Here's a sample code:

```
  create OR REPLACE package get_all_inventory_package is
  type arrayofrec is table of Inventory%rowtype index by pls_integer;
  procedure get_all_inventory (o_return_variable OUT arrayofrec);
  end;
  /
  create OR REPLACE package BODY get_all_inventory_package is
  procedure get_all_inventory (o_return_variable OUT arrayofrec)is
  return_variable arrayofrec;
  begin
  select * bulk collect into o_return_variable from Inventory;
  end;
  END;
  /

  declare
  v_receiver get_all_inventory_package.arrayofrec;
  begin
  get_all_inventory_package.get_all_inventory(v_receiver);
  for a in 1..v_receiver.count loop
  dbms_output.put_line(v_receiver(a).Inventory_column);
  end loop;
  end;
```