# Postgres json get results in one row

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

This is what I have right now

```
SELECT json_build_object(concat(name, r_id), 
       json_agg(json_build_array(value,created_at) ORDER BY created_at ASC))
FROM data
group by concat(name, r_id);
```

What this returns is 3 rows of data, I need them in the same row as a hash

Got:

row1: `{"Name1" : [["70.2", "2018-02-19T16:26:08.857134"], ["69.93", "2018-02-19T16:26:16.568789"]}`

row2: `{"Name2" : [["70.2", "2018-02-19T16:26:08.857134"], ["69.93", "2018-02-19T16:26:16.568789"]}`

row3: `{"NewName1" : [["70.2", "2018-02-19T16:26:08.857134"], ["69.93", "2018-02-19T16:26:16.568789"]}`

Expected

```
{
    "Name1": [
        ["70.2", "2018-02-19T16:26:08.857134"],
        ["69.93", "2018-02-19T16:26:16.568789"]
    ],
    "Name2": [
        ["70.2", "2018-02-19T16:26:08.857134"],
        ["69.93", "2018-02-19T16:26:16.568789"]
    ],
    "NewName1": [
        ["70.2", "2018-02-19T16:26:08.857134"],
        ["69.93", "2018-02-19T16:26:16.568789"]
    ]
}
```

Here is a sqlfiddle with this example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0b10d/1

Comment: Remove the `group by` if you want one row.

Comment: Something like this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006291/postgresql-return-result-set-as-json-array/24006432

Comment: @GordonLinoff If I remove the group by I get the error that they must be in a GROUP BY because I'm concating them to use `name` and `r_id` as the keys of the hash. If I remove the concat and group_by I do only get one row but not as expected.

Comment: @SimonBerthiaume It's very close to the second result he is looking for but I'm not entirely sure how to make It work here.

Comment: I added a sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0b10d/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the aggregate function [`json_object_agg():`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

```
select json_object_agg(name, details)
from (
    select concat(name, r_id) as name, 
           json_agg(json_build_array(value,created_at) order by created_at asc) as details
    from data
    group by concat(name, r_id)
    ) s
```

[SqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0b10d/11)