# PostgreSQL select into JSON array

Tags: json, postgresql

Having a table named `Example` with a column named `Value` and some example data in it `value1`, `value2`, `value3`.

How can I select the values in the table into a JSON array?

```
[ "value1", "value2", "value3" ]
```

Comment: Use `json_agg`?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Using `json_agg` does not work. The result should be a list of strings, not a list of objects containing those strings.

Comment: How did you use it? If you give it strings it will give you an array of strings

Comment: @RăzvanFlaviusPanda it will work. check a [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t7Ltzn2YL9SsLBgMy7tRbg/0) from Christoph answer

Comment: My bad, I was aggregating on the entire table instead of on the column. And that was returning stuff like: `[{"Value":"value1"},  {"Value":"value2"},  {"Value":"valu3"}]`

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006291/postgresql-return-result-set-as-json-array/24006432) this seems to be a good question about that topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
create table example ( value text );
insert into example values ('value1'), ('value2'), ('value3');
select json_agg(value) from example;
            json_agg            
────────────────────────────────
 ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
```