# Converting large number of database results into array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am pulling a database query that has the following info:

`id, name, roleId, roleTitle`

In the query, I am pulling for users and their roles. Each user can have 0 to N number of roles. I want to in the end have an object like this:

```
{
    id
    name
    roles: [{
       id
       title
    }]
}
```

What would the most efficient way of doing this be? Currently I am doing something like this:

```
const data = [];
arr.forEach((u) => {
   const index = data.findIndex(x => x.id === u.id);
    if (index >= 0) {
      data[index].roles.push({ id: u.roleId, title: u.roleTitle });
    } else {
      data.push({
        id: u.id,
        name: u.name,
        roles: u.roleId ? [{
          id: u.roleId,
          title: u.roleTitle,
        }] : [],
      });
    }
}
```

This solution works correctly but wasn't sure if this was the fastest way to get this done if we scale the user numbers to 10k with an average role per user of 3 or 50k and 5 roles per user

Comment: No it is needlessly slow: replace the array with a hash or a Set. Every time you try to find then index you have to walk the entire array.

Comment: If you really need to have it done client-side, then I would use Web Workers to parse this if you think your dataset will scale to 5 digits and more.

Comment: @AbanaClara I'm assuming node.js even though OP didn't tag it as such.

Comment: Can you provide some demo data

Comment: @JaredSmith That makes sense. I instantly assumed OP just took linear datasets and is trying to parse the data in the client

Comment: @AbanaClara - that is correct, this is nodejs

Comment: What database are you using? Some databases (i.e. PostgreSQL, Oracle) support JSON, in which case you could use a method like `json_agg` and do most of the work at the database level, which would be far more efficient.

Comment: @patrick3853 I am using postgres. I will have to look into `json_agg` as a solution to this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006291/postgresql-return-result-set-as-json-array/24006432

Comment: @user081608 yeah, that would likely be much faster than my answer: it would be basically be doing the same thing as my answer but in C instead of Javascript.

Comment: What is arr in your context ?  Is it array of objects ?

Comment: Do you have separate tables for user, role, and user_role?

Comment: @patrick3853 - yup, there are three joins in the query. I am working to try the suggestions from your above link

Comment: I'm working on an answer for you right now on SQL fiddle, getting close

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is actually to do this all in SQL, since you are using PostgreSQL for your database (as mentioned in comments). I don't know the exact names of your tables and columns, so you may need to tweak this, but this will get you what you want:

```sql
SELECT json_agg(t)
FROM (
  SELECT
    u.id,
    u.name,
    ro.roles
  FROM "user" u
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      ur.user_id,
      json_agg(
        json_build_object(
          'id', r.id,
          'title', r.title
        )
      ) AS roles
    FROM user_role ur
    LEFT JOIN "role" r ON r.id = ur.role_id
    GROUP BY ur.user_id
  ) ro ON ro.user_id = u.id
) t;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5f6ca/11

#### Explanation

`json_build_object` will create an object using the name / value pairs specified, so:

```sql
json_build_object(
  'id', r.id,
  'title', r.title
)
```

Combines the role `id` and `title` into a JSON object like this:

```
{id: 1, title: "Title 1"}
```

`json_agg` aggregates multiple rows into a JSON array, so it converts the role objects above into a single column that is an array of role objects per user (thanks to the `GROUP BY u.id` part of the inner subquery). The inner subquery gives us a result set like this (one row per user)

```
| user_id |                       roles                          |
|---------|------------------------------------------------------|
|    1    | [{id: 1, title: "Role 1"}, {id: 2, title: "Role 2"}] |
```

Then the subquery is joined to the user table, and all of that is wrapped in another subquery so `json_agg` can be used on the entire result and return a single json object that is an array of users with roles.

Comment: Thank you! This looks great. One last question, in the last result, it has `{"id":3,"name":"User 3","roles":[{"id" : null, "title" : null}]}`. Is there a way to return `null` for `roles` when there are no results?

Comment: @user081608 Yes, that should be possible, give me a minute to update it.

Comment: @user081608 Okay, I've updated it to return `null` for `roles` when there are no roles. Sorry for all the edits to the answer, I had trouble linking to the correct sql fiddle.

Comment: @user081608 Glad to help! Databases adding native JSON support is really powerful (MySQL added it in 5.7). Anytime you are manipulating a large data set or performing aggregation, it's usually faster to do it at the database level.

Answer (score 1):

This almost certainly isn't the most efficient possible version but is faster than what you're doing now:

```
const data = Object.values(arr.reduce((obj, {id, name, roleId, roleTitle}) => {
  if (!(id in obj)) {
    obj[id] = {
      id,
      name,
      roles: {},
    };
  }
  if (!obj[id].roles[roleId]) {
    obj[id].roles[roleId] = {
      id: roleId,
      title: roleTitle,
    };
  }
  return obj;
}, {}));
```

By using objects (hashes) instead of arrays, determining if the user is already there or if the user already has a role is a constant-time O(1) operation (the cost of the hashing function). But searching an array, depending on the search method used, is linear in the worst case O(n) and even the best case is O(log n).

You could go down the rabbit hole of micro-optimizations that will change with the wind, but choosing the correct data structures and algorithms will usually get you the most bang for your optimization buck.

I've used `Object.values` to convert back to an array at the end, if you omit this and just stick with objects it could be even faster.

Comment: Thanks Jared, makes sense. I've done this in Java before but didn't know the same concept hold true here

Comment: @user081608 yup. Javascript is getting better about datastructures. I'd stick with objects and arrays over Maps and Sets for this since it sounds like you'll probably be JSON serializing it at some point. Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
var modified_array = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    obj = (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || {});
    obj.id = x.id;
    obj.name = x.name;
    obj.roles = obj.roles || []
    obj.roles.push({ id: x.roleId, title: x.roleTitle})
    return rv;
  }, {});
};

arr = [{id:1,name:"abd",roleId: 10,roleTitle: "hello"},
       {id:1, name: "abd", roleId: 15,roleTitle: "fello"}]    
console.log( Object.values(modified_array(arr, 'id')));
```