# Select as array of tuples postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

Given table of enums

```
|id |reaction |
|-- |-------- |
|1  |laugh    |
|2  |love     |
|3  |love     |
|4  |like     |
|5  |like     |
|6  |surprised|
|7  |like     |
|8  |love     |
|9  |like     |
|10 |surprised|
```

How can I select it to get following JSON array of tuples `[reaction, count()]`?

```
[
   [laugh, 1], 
   [love, 3], 
   [like, 4], 
   [surprised, 2]
]
```

Comment: this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006291/postgresql-return-result-set-as-json-array/24006432) maybe help you.

Comment: @danial it doesn't looks like a regular JSON.

Comment: @AkhileshMishra it is, why wouldn't it be? yes, no quotes, but array of tuples is valid json

Comment: I specifically said `regular json` though it is valid. AFAIK jsob function will not give any output without quotes.

Comment: Quotes is irrelevant to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of postgres over partition by and jsonb_build_array function:

```
SELECT
    jsonb_build_array(json_reactions.reaction, count)
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT reaction, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY reaction)
    FROM
        reactions r ) AS json_reactions ;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, you are correct, updating answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can aggregate the result of a group by query:

```sql
select jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(reaction, count))
from (
  select reaction, count(*)
  from the_table
  group by reaction
) t;
```

This would return:

```json
[
  {"surprised": 2}, 
  {"like": 4}, 
  {"laugh": 1}, 
  {"love": 3}
]
```

---

Or if you really want the inner key/value pairs as a JSON array:

```sql
select jsonb_agg(array[reaction, "count"])
from (
  select reaction, count(*)::text as "count"
  from the_table
  group by reaction
) t;
```

This would return

```json
[
  ["surprised","2"],
  ["like","4"],
  ["laugh","1"],
  ["love","3"]
]
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c65f44e2b4163d5eba733e0cad742e02)