# creating json array using column name as key and column as value in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

i have table named list in a PostgreSQL database

```
create  table list (firstname text,lastname text,age integer);
insert into list values ('SHARON','XAVIER',25);
insert into list values ('RON','PETER',17);
insert into list values ('KIM','BENNY',14);

 select * from list;

 firstname | lastname | age 
-----------+----------+-----
 SHARON    | XAVIER   |  25
 RON       | PETER    |  17
 KIM       | BENNY    |  14
```

i need to create JSON array from this table like this ::

> [ column name : column value]

```
  [
    { "firstname" : "SHARON","lastname" : "XAVIER" , "age" : 25},
    { "firstname" : "RON","lastname" : "PETER" , "age" : 17},
    { "firstname" : "KIM","lastname" : "BENNY" , "age" : 14}
  ]
```

any possible options ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006291/postgresql-return-result-set-as-json-array/24006432

Hope this can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `to_jsonb()` to convert an entire row to a JSON value, then use `jsonb_agg()` to aggregate all those into a single JSON array:

```
select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(l))
from list l;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fd7f09e97b5c439f1320dcf7832ae387)