# Fetch 1:Many relation in postgreSQL as (object-relational)?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have two tables called `user` and `post` which they have data like this:

**Users Table**

```
 id | first_name | second_name 
  1     John          Doe
  2     Ellis         Mount
```

**Posts Table**

```
 id |   topic        |    body        |   author_id
  1    Internet       ...some text          1
  2    Web 3.0        ...some text          2
```

So what my question is how to how to query `posts` with the `author` user inside of it as object referring to the user who created the post.

```
[
   { 
     id:1,
     topic: Internet,
     body: ...some text, 
     author_id: 1
     author: {
       first_name: John,
       last_name: Doe
     }
   },

   { 
     id: 2,
     topic: Web 3.0,
     body: ...some text, 
     author_id: 2
     author: {
       first_name: Ellis,
       last_name: Mount
     }
   }
]
```

So, in a way to reach this, I tried something like this with `inner join:

```
SELECT *
FROM post 
INNER JOIN user
ON post.author_id = user.id;
```

unfortunately, this not fetching the data I want... so if any know how to query this please help!

Comment: Are you saying that you want your output in JSON format?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock yes you can say that or like MongoDB works.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006291/postgresql-return-result-set-as-json-array) help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON format and create JSON filed.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d872c27ec03a94153fb0fb6b850b7fac)

```sql
SELECT
  post.*,
  json_build_object(
    'first_name',
    first_name,
    'last_name',
    second_name
  ) as author
FROM post 
INNER JOIN "user"
ON post.author_id = "user".id;
```

Comment: Thank you bro this did the trick.