# Query relational database and map the data into structure with nested slice of another structure type

Tags: go

What are good approaches to query data from SQL Database and map it into a structure which contains a slice of another structure type?

In my case, I am using `Postgres SQL`, `pgx` to query data, and `scany` to map the row results into objects.

I have a posts table and comments table. The relationship is that one post can have many comments.

**These are my models representing the database tables**

```
package models

type Post struct {
    Id int64
    // more fields

    Comments []Comment
}

type Comment struct {
    Id     int64
    PostId int64
    // more fields

    Post Post
}
```

**This is my `PostRepository` object**

```
package repository

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/georgysavva/scany/pgxscan"
    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/pgxpool"
    "kosev.com/databases/models"
)

type PostRepository struct {
    dbPool *pgxpool.Pool
}

func NewPostRepository(dbPool *pgxpool.Pool) *PostRepository {
    return &PostRepository{
        dbPool: dbPool,
    }
}

func (pr *PostRepository) GetAll() []models.Post {
    query := `SELECT * FROM posts
              LEFT OUTER JOIN "comments"
              ON "comments".post_id  = posts.id;`

    var posts []models.Post

    rows, _ := pr.dbPool.Query(context.Background(), query)

    err := pgxscan.ScanAll(&posts, rows)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err.Error())
    }

    return posts
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get all `posts` and in each post to have a slice of the corresponding `comments` for this `post`

Now I know that I can

- query all posts
- loop through the posts and build a query that will get me the comments for each post
- add the appropriate comments into the slice of the appropriate post

I am wondering if there is the better solution, one which will only require me to execute the query and some `Scan()` method that is smart enough to add the comments inside the posts.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the json capacity of postgres, it could be OK for simple database but I'm not sure about the perfs for more complexes queries

1. docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:

  db:
    image: postgres:10.16
    depends_on:
      - adminer  
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: test
    volumes:
      - ./volume:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./sql/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  adminer:
    image: adminer:latest
    environment:
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER: localhost
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

2. folder sql to init db

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comments (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  post_id INTEGER,
  txt TEXT
);

INSERT INTO posts (title)
VALUES ('first'),('second');

INSERT INTO comments (post_id, txt)
VALUES (1,'cool'), (1,'notcool'), (2,'third');
```

3. on adminer (localhost:8080) you can try this query

```
    SELECT p.id, p.title, json_agg(c) as comments
    FROM posts p LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.post_id = p.id
    GROUP BY p.id;
```

you will get the nested comments in json format

```
1   first   [{"id":1,"post_id":1,"txt":"cool"}, {"id":2,"post_id":1,"txt":"notcool"}]
2   second  [{"id":3,"post_id":2,"txt":"third"}]
```

now it's possible to scan it's nested struct fields

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5"
)

type Post struct {
    Id       int64
    Title    string
    Comments []Comment
}

type Comment struct {
    Id  int64
    Txt string
}

func main() {
    urlExample := "postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/test"
    conn, err := pgx.Connect(context.Background(), urlExample)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Unable to connect to database: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer conn.Close(context.Background())

    rows, err := conn.Query(context.Background(),
        `SELECT p.id, p.title,  
    json_agg(c) as comments
        FROM posts p
        LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.post_id = p.id
        GROUP BY p.id;`)

    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        var post Post
        err := rows.Scan(&post.Id, &post.Title, &post.Comments)
        if err != nil {
            panic(fmt.Sprintf("%v", err))
        }
        fmt.Println(post)
    }
}
```

ref : [example page for query postgres](https://github.com/jackc/pgx)
[postgres building json example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006291/postgresql-return-result-set-as-json-array)