# How find one JSONB item from JSONB array in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have this table:

| id | period_type | period | commission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | Daily | 10 | 10 |
| 123456 | Monthly | 3 | 11 |
| 123456 | Daily | 5 | 12 |
| 123456 | Monthly | 1 | 13 |
| 123457 | Monthly | 6 | 14 |
| 123457 | Daily | 5 | 15 |
| 123457 | Monthly | 9 | 16 |

(Period type is int 1&2, but for example I wrote it by text)

I need get records with id and single jsonb with period_type, period and commission column. This jsonb must have max period with max period type. For example, id - 123456, period_type - 'Monthly', period - 3, commission - 11.

I know how get array of periods (`jsonb_build_object` and `jsonb_agg`), but don't know how get 1 period with such conditions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL return result set as JSON array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006291/postgresql-return-result-set-as-json-array) ?  Or could you post the desired output based on the given input?

Comment: @Luuk I don't think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard Top-1-Per-Group problem. Use `ROW_NUMBER` to get the top value in each group, then `jsonb_agg` to aggregate it up into a JSON array.

```sql
SELECT jsonb_agg(m) 
FROM (
    SELECT
      m.id,
      m.period_type,
      m.period,
      m.commission
    FROM (
        SELECT 
          m.*,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY period_type DESC, period DESC) AS rn
        FROM mytable m
    ) m
    WHERE rn = 1
) m;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/85oRTyPw)

Comment: Thanks, that answer is really good for me, so I just need adapt it for my ORM

Answer (score 0):

Next query can be written easier, but I am always seem to have problem when multiple MAX values pop-up in 1 query (like getting the commission for the max period for the max period_type):

```
  SELECT
    m3.id,
    m3.period_type,
    m3.period,
    m4.commission
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      m.id,
      m.period_type,
      max(m.period) as period
    FROM mytable m
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT
        id,
        max(period_type) over (partition by id ) period_type
      FROM mytable
      ) x on x.id=m.id and x.period_type=m.period_type
    GROUP BY m.id, m.period_type
  ) m3
  INNER JOIN mytable m4 on m4.id=m3.id 
                       and m4.period_type=m3.period_type 
                       and m4.period=m3.period
```

it retruns:

| id | period_type | period | commission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | Monthly | 3 | 11 |
| 123457 | Monthly | 9 | 16 |

This query can be used as a sub-query to get JSON:

```
SELECT json_agg(m5) 
from (
  SELECT
    m3.id,
    m3.period_type,
    m3.period,
    m4.commission
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      m.id,
      m.period_type,
      max(m.period) as period
    FROM mytable m
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT
        id,
        max(period_type) over (partition by id ) period_type
      FROM mytable
      ) x on x.id=m.id and x.period_type=m.period_type
    GROUP BY m.id, m.period_type
  ) m3
  INNER JOIN mytable m4 on m4.id=m3.id 
                       and m4.period_type=m3.period_type 
                       and m4.period=m3.period
) m5
```

output:

```
[{"id":123456,"period_type":"Monthly","period":3,"commission":11}, 
 {"id":123457,"period_type":"Monthly","period":9,"commission":16}]
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/eJJj4haK)

Comment: I think you are way overcomplicating it, you just need `ROW_NUMBER`

Comment: @Charlieface: Yes, True, But here my experience in the field is missing tooo much, so sometimes I get to an answer the looooong way 

Comment: Not sure what you mean, `ROW_NUMBER` still works. See my answer and https://dbfiddle.uk/85oRTyPw